# ToggleClass hide not triggering the CSS events

Tags: jquery, css

I have this very weird problem with my HTML mobile app which am really breaking my head for past 2 days. To start with am working a mobile app which have Facebook kind vertical Menu on the Left top.

I am binding click event to a menuOption from the above said vertical menu item to perform ToggleClass("hide") method. Though the event does the job perfectly am not able to see any changes in the UI side, but when I checked the DOM it seems the toggleClass has worked perfectly. When I give a spacebar and do any sort of changes in the External CSS file then only correponding CSS  of toggledClass is loaded.

Also one more relevant point, CSS DISPLAY property for NavigationMenu div is absolute and MainPage is Fixed. When I change the prop of MainPage to relative everything works fine, but I want it to be Fixed only.

Similarly when am binding the toggleEvent to a button in the main page also its working, only when the click event is binded to the menuoptions in NavigationMenu div element

```
<div>
    <span class="header1">Header</span>
    <label class="dtl1 hide  ">Details</label>
    <span class="header2">Header</span>
    <label class="dtl2 hide">Details</label>
</div>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$('span').click(function() {
  var selIndex =  $("span").index(event.currentTarget);
  $('label').toggleClass("hide");
});
```

On a whole I would like to know why the toggleClass,addClass,removeClass are not triggering the CSS properties once the DOM was changed?

Comment: Is your `$('span').click(function() { }};` in `$(document).ready(fcuntion() { })`?

Comment: try plain js, maybe is better: (element.classList.contains('class'))?element.classList.remove('class'):element.classList.add('class');

Comment: @cox I think jQuery should be stable enough and well tested and the OP surely doesn't have to rewrite to plain js if don't want to.

Comment: @wumm I think the problem is not there. Both js/jquery do this. Maybe a console.log() tell's him if the selector do match something, the elements are loaded or the event fired.

Comment: There is too much of your code/HTML you don't show. Please make a fiddle.

Comment: Have you tried `$('label').toggle()`? Maybe the problem it's on the CSS

Comment: @maurizioless, plainly I wud same the CSS was not applied after toggleClass.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/L6rd57gk/1/

### js

```
$('span').on('click', function() {
  var selIndex =  $(this).index();
    $(this).next().toggleClass("hide");
});
```

### css

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}

span{
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Why don't you put details inside the span, or put a data- identifier so you don't have to use `.next()`, also why do you need the *index* of the span?